# Android get RSSI of specific device (or the whole list!)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, rssi

I've seen some apps on the playstore that can read the RSSI of all devices in range via Bluetooth, how is that possible? I'm currently running a code that can get me one and only one RSSI (which is the nearest one available).

Any possible way to get the RSSI of a specific device? Or even better, get the RSSI of all the devices in range?

I'm using the EXTRA_RSSI code at the moment, but I need to get the RSSI of the whole list or a specific device.

Here's the method I'm using (it's working fine, but again, only the nearest is getting capted)

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            //Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

            //for (BluetoothDevice dv : pairedDevices) {

                String action = intent.getAction();
                if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    int rssit = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
                    int rssi = Math.abs(rssit); // Just for visual analysis
                    String name = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME);

                    if (!l_name.contains(name)) {
                        RadioButton Rb = new RadioButton(getBaseContext());
                        Rb.setId(l_name.size());
                        Rb.setText(name);
                        Rb.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD, R.style.TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_DropDownItem);
                        Rb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                s_name = ((RadioButton) view).getText().toString();
                            }
                        });

                        l_name.add(name);
                        ((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup)).addView(Rb);
                    }

                    //if (s_name != name) return;

                    String RSSI = "";
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(name);
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.range)).setText(RSSI + " " + rssit);
                }
            //}
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `onReceive()` callback *should* be getting called for every nearby advertising device. If you do `BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);` then you should see that you're actually getting different device instances for each call to `onReceive()`. Eventually they will start to repeat, but if there are 3 advertising devices nearby you should get at least 3 callbacks. Log `BluetoothDevice#getAddress()` to confirm the behavior.